# React.js cant find image with variable in it's path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I didn't use React before, so my question could be silly, but anyway, i have simple project with TailwindCSS, i want to check if image exists and set a class pointing to that image, but Reacts gives me an error.

App.js:

```js
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Tools from './Tools';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <Header/>
      </header>
      <main className='flex w-[80vw] mx-auto'>
        <div id='tools'>
          <Tools/>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Tools.js:

```js
const Tools = () => {
    return (
        <main className="my-4">
            <h1 className="text-4xl">Инструменты</h1>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {Box("Big test", "TESTS ARE COOL", "construction.png", "#!")}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

const Box = ({name, desc, img, href}) => {
    let imgExists;
    try{
        require(`./img/tools/${img}`);
        imgExists = true;
    }
    catch(err){
        imgExists = false;
    }
    return (
        <li>
            <a href={href}>
                <div>
                    <h2>{name}</h2>
                    <p>{desc}</p>
                </div>
                <div className={imgExists === true ? `bg-[url('./img/tools/${img}')]` : "not-found"}></div>
            </a>
        </li>
    )
}

export default Tools
```

(There are no errors in Header.js)

Error:

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './img/tools/${img}' in '/home/anime/PRACTICE/ddracenet/src'
ERROR in ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css) 5:36-82
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './img/tools/${img}' in '/home/anime/PRACTICE/ddracenet/src'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check the path of the image**, because if React says it can't resolve that means it can't find, in most cases.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './img/tools/${img}' in '/home/anime/PRACTICE/ddracenet/src'
```

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs when webpack is bundling your javascript code. Webpack searches all the dependencies and because the required image doesn't exists, it throws error.
To solve the problem, you should send request to the image src and check the result.

Here's my code.

```js
import Axios from "axios";
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const Tools = () => {
    return (
        <main className="my-4">
            <h1 className="text-4xl">Инструменты</h1>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <Box name="Big test" desc="TESTS ARE COOL" img="construction.png" href="#!" />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

const Box = ({name, desc, img, href}) => {
    const [imgExists, setImgExists] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get(`./img/tools/${img}`).then(() => {
            setImgExists(true);
        }).catch(() => {
            setImgExists(false);
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <li>
            <a href={href}>
                <div>
                    <h2>{name}</h2>
                    <p>{desc}</p>
                </div>
                <div className={imgExists === true ? `bg-[url('./img/tools/${img}')]` : "not-found"}></div>
            </a>
        </li>
    )
}
```

I haven't run this code but I'm sure it works perfectly.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, but that didn't work, i tested few other methods and assigning path to variable and changing it seems working!

Answer (score 0):

I used checking image from [@ligntbulb.dev2022's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72918505/13846725) and decided to assing path there instead, everything seems working!

```js
import Axios from "axios";
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

const Box = ({name, desc, img, href}) => {
    let path = `img/tools/${img}`;
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get(path).then(() => {
            //pass
        }).catch(() => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            path = "not-found";
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <li>
            <a href={href}>
                <div>
                    <h2>{name}</h2>
                    <p>{desc}</p>
                </div>
                <div className={path}></div>
            </a>
        </li>
    )
}
```